# NetBeans 7.4 does not start on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: java, netbeans

I have downloaded the `sh` file from the official website and installed `NetBeans 7.4`, but it does not start at all. I have also tried of running it through the command line, but after a few seconds I get the control of the command line again, without any error being visualized.

Actually I had already installed `NetBeans 7.3.1` and it was working up to a week ago, when it stopped starting, so I tried to install the newer version. I have also tried to delete the folders and reinstall both version from scratch, but I get the same result.

What do you think the problem could be?

Comment: What Java version is installed?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_17", 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02), 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)